# "You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India."

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

When I used stripe payment gateway in Laravel 9, an exception occurred:

> You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India. Please refer to https://stripe.com/docs/payments for accepting payments

```
 public function makePayment(Request $request)
     {
        $input = $request->all();

        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_.............KTt');
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'source' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
            'description' => "10 cucumbers from Roger's Farm",
            'amount' => 2000,
            'currency' => 'inr'
          ]);
          dd('$charge');
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: If you want to test INDIAN currency, use the credit card number as "4000 0035 6000 0008" with future expiry month and year and any CVV number. That works

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [PaymentIntent APIs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create) instead:

I invite you to refer to this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) in order to build a complete integration with Stripe new APIs.

Or you can follow this [migration guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration) (From Charges API to PaymentIntent API)

For Indian international payments, you may need to take into consideration [these requirements](https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments).